# List of contents of entire blog

Tags: customization

There is a widget categories which prints categories as tree, for example:

```
category1
  subcategory1
  subcategory2
category2
  subcategory1
```

I would like to print whole content of blog together with articles not as widget but on main page as normal text like:

```
category1
  subcategory1
    news1
    news2
  subcategory2
    news1
category2
  subcategory1   
    news1
    news2
```

What is the way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is some idea in ['Hierarchical Category List with Post Titles'](http://www.transformationpowertools.com/wordpress/hierarchical-category-list-with-post-titles) which might need some adaptation to get exactly what you want.